# Integrate Grabkit with cocoa pods in existing project

Tags: cocoapods

I have integrated Grabkit in my project via adding submodules. I want to add grabkit via cocoa pods. I surfed web alot. I have created a pod file.

```
pod 'Grabkit', :git => 'https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit.git'
```

I have downloaded latest podspec file from  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/05def154728953519546ee0c648a82f293d02f4f/grabKit/1.4/grabKit.podspec

When I run `pod install` or `pod update` I get following error:

```
$ pod update
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.29.0 is available.

Pre-downloading: `Grabkit` from `https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit.git`
[!] No podspec found for `Grabkit` in /path-of-my-project/Pods/Grabkit/Grabkit.podspec
```

Please suggest !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to download the latest podspec. The specs are automatically managed by the `pod` command line tool and there is a clone of the entire specs repo in `~/.cocoapods`. The issue here is the case. It is [`grabKit`](https://github.com/cocoapods/specs/tree/master/grabKit) notice the lowercase 'g'

Comment: The reason i want to integrate it with pods is because when adding it as submodules and pushing over git, my team is facing problem with its integration. I am wondering why. So i thought to do it with pods.

By lowercase 'g' do you mean
pod 'grabKit', :git => 'https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit.git'
instead of 'GrabKit'

Comment: Yes. At least in the first occurrence. The second depends on your URL I suppose.